# How to load quickdic dictionary into C#

Tags: c#, database, dictionary

I have downloaded a dictionary file from http://code.google.com/p/quickdic-dictionary/
But the file extension is .quickdic and is not plain text.

How can I load the quickdic dictionaries (.quickdic) into c# to make simple word queries?

Comment: The extension of the file is largely irrelivant; what matters is how the file is formatted; the extension is just a hint about what that format might possibly be.

Comment: The point is it's not plain text; I took a look at one of the .quickdic files in Notepad++ and while there is some plain text it's obvious they're not just tab-delimited or CSVs.

Comment: This is a question that should be directed at the guy's who wrote it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I browsed through the git code, and a few things stuck out.

First, in the DictionaryActivity.java file, there is the following in onCreate():

```
    final String name = application.getDictionaryName(dictFile.getName());
    this.setTitle("QuickDic: " + name);
    dictRaf = new RandomAccessFile(dictFile, "r");
    dictionary = new Dictionary(dictRaf);
```

That Dictionary Class is not the built in class with Java, but is here according to the imports:

```
    import com.hughes.android.dictionary.engine.Dictionary;
```

When I look there, it shows a constructor for a Dictionary taking a RandomAccessFile as the parameter. Here's that source code:

```
public Dictionary(final RandomAccessFile raf) throws IOException {
dictFileVersion = raf.readInt();
if (dictFileVersion < 0 || dictFileVersion > CURRENT_DICT_VERSION) {
  throw new IOException("Invalid dictionary version: " + dictFileVersion);
}
creationMillis = raf.readLong();
dictInfo = raf.readUTF();

// Load the sources, then seek past them, because reading them later disrupts the offset.
try {
  final RAFList<EntrySource> rafSources = RAFList.create(raf, new EntrySource.Serializer(this), raf.getFilePointer());
  sources = new ArrayList<EntrySource>(rafSources);
  raf.seek(rafSources.getEndOffset());

  pairEntries = CachingList.create(RAFList.create(raf, new PairEntry.Serializer(this), raf.getFilePointer()), CACHE_SIZE);
  textEntries = CachingList.create(RAFList.create(raf, new TextEntry.Serializer(this), raf.getFilePointer()), CACHE_SIZE);
  if (dictFileVersion >= 5) {
    htmlEntries = CachingList.create(RAFList.create(raf, new HtmlEntry.Serializer(this), raf.getFilePointer()), CACHE_SIZE);
  } else {
    htmlEntries = Collections.emptyList();
  }
  indices = CachingList.createFullyCached(RAFList.create(raf, indexSerializer, raf.getFilePointer()));
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
  final IOException ioe = new IOException("RuntimeException loading dictionary");
  ioe.initCause(e);
  throw ioe;
}
final String end = raf.readUTF(); 
if (!end.equals(END_OF_DICTIONARY)) {
  throw new IOException("Dictionary seems corrupt: " + end);
}
```

So, anyway, this is how his java code reads the file in.

Hopefully, this helps you simulate this in C#.

From here you would probably want to see how he is serializing the EntrySource, PairEntry, TextEntry, and HtmlEntry, as well as the indexSerializer.

Next look to see how RAFList.create() works.

Then see how that result is incorporated in creating a CachingList using CachingList.create()

Disclaimer: I'm not sure if the built in serializer in C# uses the same format as Java's, so you may need to simulate that too :)